# I want to show a specific customers balance in a panel

Tags: python, django

I want to show a specific customers balance in a panel for that I want to fetch the specific customers balance and want to show it in a page or somewhere else.Like this example:
user 1 has 100$ and user 2 has 200$ so when user 1 will login the page will show 100$ and when user 2 login he will be shown 200$.But I am confused here to complete this task.How can I do this ?
I have a coin var which is working as a balance.
Here is my Model for Customer :

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=1)
    email = models.EmailField( default=1)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    coin = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone_number


    def register(self):
        self.save()


    def get_customer(phone_number):
        try:
            return Customer.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number)
        except:
            return False
```

Answer (score 1):

you are wrong on `get_customer` definition

```py
def get_customer(phone_number):
    try:
        return Customer.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number)
    except:
        return False
```

in `Customer` class if you are not in a `classmethod` 1st parameters is `self`

```py
def get_customer(self):
    return self
```

So you will return directly `Customer` instance.

In your view just call :

```py
customer = Customer.objects.get(phone_number=phone_number)
```

and add it to the context.

PS : dont try/except without exception, in your code call `Customer.DoesNotExist`

Answer (score 0):

First, every User should have a Customer model.

You see, Django does not view your CustomerModel as a User unless we specify this. instead of specifying, I find it better to just add a field to your table. Using a Foreignkey so each Customer will have a unique User.

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, default=1)
    email = models.EmailField( default=1)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    coin = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
    # ADD THIS LINE BELOW
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='customer')
```

In your views.py

```
class YourView(View):
    
    def get(self, request):
            return render(request, './yourpagehere.html', context=self.get_context(request))  
    
    def get_context(self, request):
        
        context = {'CustomerObject': Customer.objects.get(user=request.user)}
        return context
```

Then in your template your can access the value using the following.

```
<p>{{CustomerObject.coin}}<p>
```

And if you wish to show this value only when a User is logged in. you could do the following in your template.

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<p>{{CustomerObject.coin}}<p>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Customer matching query does not exist. getting this error

Comment: i dont want to User i just want to show customers coin. I don't want to use User  here